# Ionic 3 resolution of images

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

can someone tell me, is there some standard for resolution and quality of images used in ionic 3 app? 
Do i need to use some particular resolution, so it can scale on each device, and also to have some normal size of images?

Comment: What u want ?? i mean u want image from camera ??

Comment: If you are using the camera plugin u can use [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/)

Comment: @KishanOza i mean on images from assets, i don't want images from camera or gallery from phone, i mean on images from application assets

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about images from the assets, it's like a common website you could use media queries.

For my apps, I don't consider these problematic, I assume all users have now a good device and a good network. Maybe it's a bad habit. I would like to know how other developers do.

Comment: this is first time i develop hybrid application, also first time using ionic, yes, i am loading images from assets, but i am not sure on what resolution to create all images, ionic it self will adjust resolution for each device as i can see in testing mode, but for image size i am not sure on what resolution to make images, because of the application size on store i am asking this question, i don't want to application be big because of images

Comment: I see. i don't have a lot of images in my apps so I don't give importance to that. And when it's the case, it's for images from API's and external servers. But maybe you would wanna look for free demos here with open source code and then know how other developers deal with images assets. 
http://showcase.ionicframework.com/apps/top

Comment: Hi! I was browsing the ionic documentation when I read that, I thought it may be interesting for you if you have a lots of images in your app https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/